# Search in Visual Studio Closes Sln

Tags: visual-studio

Every time I search in visual studio using CTRL+F - it seems to get to the last search item and shut down ? Then I have to reopen the solution every time and start again.

Does anyone have idea why this would happen?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Do you have the latest service packs for visual studio installed?
- Is there enough hd space in the drive where windows and/or visual studio is installed
- You can search in the microsoft knowledge base if this problem is already known.
- maybe you installed a faulty plugin for visual studio which causes the errror, you may try to disable/uninstall it
- If nothing helps maybe a reinstall of visual studio could help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, have you applied the latest service pack to your IDE?

If yes, I'd start troubleshooting this by disabling all VS add-ins you might be running. If this does not help, then try creating a new project and see if the same problem occurs there.

If it does, then you might need to re-install Visual Studio. If not, then you might try recreating your project bit by bit (in case it's not too big yet) while trying if the search is still working.

Comment: yeah just checked all my updates and running latest. seems might try the compartmental build approach as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on an x64 system? If so check these out. There are apparently some issues that arise when using certain utilities.

http://www.nateirwin.net/2007/12/20/visual-studio-2008-crashes-on-ctrl-f/
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=311712